# How do I shift the image and text section below my main image as its overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I want the text and image below this main full-size image section as normally we see in websites usually. I am new to programming. 
I want to make below the main image a section with the image on right and text as shown in image link below.
Here is my code :

`http://jsfiddle.net/165hkr8x/1/`

`<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/165hkr8x/1/embed/"></script>`

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI06J.png)
[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiUnE.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please share your code so that we can help you better?

Comment: Hi Helenesh, can you please check now, thanks for welcoming, and really thanks for replying.

Comment: Can you also please provide more details on the desired behaviour? I don't clearly understand your issue.

Comment: Helenesh this is what I want to make, I just couldn't figure this out : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiUnE.png

Answer (score 0):

I thought, that I get your question. I've a link for you Try this it will help you.
[Float Image](https://www.hostpapa.in/knowledgebase/align-float-images-website/)

[Find the image is this your expectation?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdSqp.png)

Comment: Sir, the problem I am having is even after closing div in my code before container1 in html and the image and text is still not starting in new block below the main image, can you please check the images I attached.

Comment: I can't open your images. It shows 'The site can't be reached' error. And also I can't understand what u asking. I saw your code and I've execute it. But still I can't find your requirement there.   Just open the image I've attached in the answer section. And confirm is that your requirment or not?

Comment: Thanks Joseph but this is what I want to make : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiUnE.png

Comment: This is not a correct way to ask a help. Here the people help you to do some very rare solutions if they know. But your requirement looks like to create a new page. You can do this easily with the help of **Bootstrap** templates . You can easily download it in web. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, I understand that, but I couldn't figure whether the problem is with my div tag or something else in my code as I can't achieve what I am trying to.

Comment: That affects more than one class in style and you have the source. And you require lot of things. So indicate a single problem is difficult in your page

Comment: I want to shift the cats description and image block below the main image, this is the single thing I am requesting help for.

Comment: www.linkedin.com/in/maria-anto-joseph-468074170  this is my LInkedIn account. Just message me there

Comment: I have sent an invitation, can you please check it. Thanks, Abhishek